# How to check if a file download is complete in Web API

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api, export-to-excel

I am working on a task where user can download data in excel format. 
The data is dynamically generated (as generic list)and then written as excel file, which is working perfectly.

**Problem:**

The problem I am facing is, when the data is huge, it takes several seconds to download the file. During that time, I need to show some kind of progress/ indication to the end users (let's say, downloading.... message). With the current code, I am not able to track when the file download is complete...

Here is my **code**,

**JS code which passes web api method and search criteria**

```
var request = {};
request.Code = codeDdl.find(':selected').val();

$.blockUI({ message: '<h3>Downloading...</h3>' });
//Export to Excel all records
$().largeDownload("api/FileDownload/GetWorkQueueList", {
   'request': JSON.stringify(request)
});
```

**JS code which reads search criteria and pass it to web api method:**

```
(function (d) {
    d.fn.largeDownload = function (a, b, c) { void 0 !== c ? (c = c.toUpperCase(), "GET" != c && (c = "POST")) : c = "POST"; if (void 0 === b || !1 == b) b = d().parse_url(a), a = b.url, b = b.params; var e = d("<form></form"); e.attr("method", c); e.attr("action", a); for (var f in b) a = d("<input />"), a.attr("type", "hidden"), a.attr("name", f), a.attr("value", b[f]), a.appendTo(e); d("body").append(e); e.bind("submit", DownloadedCallback); e.submit() }; d.fn.parse_url = function (a) {
        if (-1 == a.indexOf("?")) return { url: a, params: {} }; var b = a.split("?"), a = b[0], c = {}, b = b[1].split("&"), e = {}, d; for (d in b) {
            var g =
            b[d].split("="); e[g[0]] = g[1]
        } c.url = a; c.params = e; return c
    }
})(jQuery);
```

**Web API**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetWorkQueueList()
    {
        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var currentContext = HttpContext.Current;

        try
        {
            string strRequest = currentContext.Request.Form["request"];
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var request = serializer.Deserialize<ViewRequest>(strRequest);
            request.QueryAllRecords = true;
            var workQueueList = MappingManager.GetWorkQueueList(request);

            var legacyExcelView = //get data as generic list
            ....
            ....

            var fileBytes = ExcelManager.GetExcelData<WQExcelView>(legacyExcelView);
            var stream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
            resp.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
            resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            resp.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "WorkQueueList.xlsx" };
            resp.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "UTF-8");
            return resp;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            resp.Content = new StringContent(ex.Message);
            return resp;
        }
    }
```

**What I've tried:**

In the largeDownload javascript function, I added the DownloadedCallback which does not seem to work as I expect. It is fired immediately and way before the download is complete.

**Question:**

How to check if a file download is complete in Web API method... What should I do to display a progress bar until the file download dialog is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

We typically solve the problem with 2-3 API calls. Our applications are written in Java; however, the same basic principle applies here.

The first call is to initiate the large SQL query, large file creation, etc. in a **separate thread**. That request returns immediately, sometimes with an id to refer to the original request.

While rows in the CSV are being written in the spawned thread, we write two property values in the original thread for the number of rows processed and total rows. If it's a large SQL statement we often batch the statement itself into several limited SQL statements so that progress values can be set incrementally and displayed, instead of sitting at 0% for a while and then snapping to 100%. Breaking up the SQL statements often comes at only an added cost of milliseconds but provides a ton of value in terms of the user experience.

We have a second API call that is polled and then returns the property values for the number processed and total count. This is what we use to animate our progress bar. When that hits 100% or a status flag on the response of that call changes, we often request the finished file in a separate API call. You could also return the file pointer/path in the same progress call.

Comment: thanks for providing some direction. I am not sure whether I will be able to break the sql statement... my sql statement is very complex (connects several tables) and brings lots of data.

Comment: Understandable. You might want to profile where most of the time is spent right now. Often, the bulk of the time is spent in the SQL call. You wouldn't have to modify the query very much—you would specify a limit, and then increment the starting index or offset each time to request the next set of rows (setting your progress properties as you do).

Comment: Also, It looks like you're using jQuery—take a look at the Deferred Object: https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/. You can contain all of your initial and progress requests in a single class and notify the caller when you have progress updates and when the file is complete.

Comment: Sure, I will look at the deferred object.